# Dismiss copy/paste contextual menu and remove selection in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in which I've implemented a single tap gesture recognizer. I don't have any recognizer for long hold, though my problem is in making a selection. Issues:

- Select some text in a UIWebView, select copy from contextual menu. Menu should disappear.
- Long hold to make a text selection, single tap gesture is also getting called.
- If text is selected, a single tap elsewhere should remove the selection like in Safari.

…

```
func createGestureRecognizer() {
    // single tap
    let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleSingleTap:")
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapGesture.delegate = self
    singleTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    webView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view.isDescendantOfView(self.webView) {
        return true
    }
    return true
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if otherGestureRecognizer.isKindOfClass(UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        otherGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(gestureRecognizer)
        // println("added failure requirement to: \(otherGestureRecognizer)")
    }
    return true
}

func handleSingleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    …
}
```

**EDIT:** It is sort of working. Problem: Making an initial text selection requires a longer hold than normal. A normal long hold that would normally make a selection calls my single tap recognizer without selecting any text.

```
func handleSingleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let selection = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.getSelection().toString()")!
    if selection == "" {
        // do stuff
    } else {
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = false
        webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()")
    }
```

Comment: Question seems ambiguous! When you select some text in Uiwebview,press copy and then remove cut,copy and paste option from uiwebview. right?

Comment: @empedocle does it work to not have the contextual menu at all?

Comment: @subbu Initially I had issues with dismissing the contextual menu after selecting text and then copying. Sort of working. check my updates.